# Login form writes that the ' ' already exists

Tags: python, django, authentication

So, i have a problem. I have a login form, but when i try to login it writes that ' ' is already exists. How is it possible?If user has an account it means that it'll exists. But why i get this mistake?

**views.py**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(email=cd['email'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form is not valid')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

I get a mistake:

`<ul class="errorlist"><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>User with this  already exists.</li></ul></li></ul>`

**Login form**

```
class LoginForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password']

        widgets = {
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-email',
                'placeholder': 'email'
            }),
            'password': PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-password',
                'placeholder': 'password'
            })
        }
```

**User model**

```
class User(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Author'),
        ('2', 'Customer'),
        ('3', 'Author and Customer')
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='', blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=128, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=CHOICES, default='Customer')
    about = models.TextField(max_length=512, verbose_name='', blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a `ModelForm` has no `instance` specified it means it is being used to *create* an instance and hence when `is_valid` is called on your form it finds that the username you provide *already* exists and hence it returns `False`. For this reason a form used to log a user in needs to be a plain `Form` class.

Moving further Django already provides a built in form that can be used for authentication [`django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm). Looking at your implementation you have a custom user model with email as the `USERNAME_FIELD`? The `AuthenticationForm` is versatile enough to handle this so you can directly use that in your view (or if you want to customize the form widgets you may inherit from it).

If you want to set attributes on the widgets, simply inherit from `AuthenticationForm` and set them in the forms `__init__` method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-email', 'placeholder': 'email'})
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-password', 'placeholder': 'password'})
```

Next use this form in your view:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request, request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form is not valid')
    else:
        form = LoginForm(request)
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: how can i do that without django built-in class?Because idk how to add styles to AuthenticationForm

Comment: it still doesn't work, i don't want to use username, i need email

Comment: @Ihor Only the field name in the form is `username`, it will be rendered as email to the template because the `AuthenticationForm` is coded in such a way that it will use the `USERNAME_FIELD` of the model which is set as `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to find the field and change this field with respect to that. "It doesn't work" - did you even try it?

Comment: @Ihor You have to render it as `{{ form.username }}` if you previously rendered `{{ form.email }}` (I assume this as you haven't added your template to the question)

Comment: oh, yes, sorry, it's a little bit unsual for me to use built-in methods.
I've tried and it gives me 'Form is not valid' message still

Comment: @Ihor I notice your model doesn't inherit from `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`? Your form is not valid because a model form (which is what your registration form is from this question of yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67547076/how-to-implement-suitable-login-form-for-my-registration-form-and-model-user) won't hash a password while `authenticate` assumes the password is hashed. Also for custom user models you should inherit from one of the above classes.

Comment: I need just to inherit from AbstractUser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232452/discussion-between-abdul-aziz-barkat-and-ihor).