# How to implement suitable login form for my registration form and model User?

Tags: python, django, authentication, registration

So, i have such model

```
class User(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Author'),
        ('2', 'Customer'),
        ('3', 'Author and Customer')
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='', blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=128, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, verbose_name='')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=CHOICES, default='Customer')
    about = models.TextField(max_length=512, verbose_name='', blank=True)
```

and such register form

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
```

it seems like that

[image]

and my view for registration form

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Successfull!")
        else:
            return render(register, 'account/register.html')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'form': form})
```

but my login view doesn't work(it always gives me invalid data)
What would be the best login view for my forms and models?

Comment: first you could check what you get in `request` - maybe you have different values then you expect. As I rember validation should gives some information about wrong data to display it in HTML as warnings. If you would get it then you would see which value makes problem

Comment: you ask about `login` view but you show `registration` view. It seems you show wrong code and you search problem in wrong place. And if you can't login then maybe first you should check in database if you have values which you expect. Maybe you put it with some extra chars/values and now it fit to values which you use when you try to login.

Comment: i copy data from database, and i asked about appropriate login view to this register view